How to presign AWS SQS ReceiveMessage request in sdk v2?
Following the announcement of EOS of AWS golang sdk v1 by July 31, 2025, I'm migrating the code to v2.
I'm trying to migrate this piece of v1 code to v2:
type Service {
    sqsService *sqs.SQS
}
....

func (s *Service) getSignedRequestsURL(queueURL string, maxNumOfMessages, visibilityTimeout, waitTimeSeconds int64) (string, error) {
    req, _ := s.sqsService.ReceiveMessageRequest(&sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
        QueueUrl:            aws.String(queueURL),
        MaxNumberOfMessages: aws.Int64(maxNumOfMessages),
        VisibilityTimeout:   aws.Int64(visibilityTimeout),
        WaitTimeSeconds:     aws.Int64(waitTimeSeconds),
    })

    exp := 20 * time.Minute
    signedURL, err := req.Presign(exp)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(signedURL)), nil
}

Using the v2 sdk, now there is an SQS client that you can use to call to receive the messages directly
var sqsClient *sqs.Client
...

res, err := sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(ctx, &sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
    QueueUrl:            aws.String(queueURL),
    ....
})



How can I mimic the req.Presign(exp) functionality to sign SQS receive message URL?
Do I need to constructer the URL/request by hand and do it manually or AWS provide idiomatic way to do it? I don't see where they expose the request data so users can interact and modify it before it being sent..

You can customize the authentication workflow, but first of all the client is now able to automatically sign your service requests:

You can use Amazon Web Services SDKs to access Amazon SQS using your favorite programming language. The SDKs perform tasks such as the following automatically:

Cryptographically sign your service requests
Retry requests
Handle error responses


Usually sqs.NewFromConfig with a configuration containing the necessary credentials should be enough.

Note that i need the presigned url, not the signed.
